# How to trigger error using Trap command

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling, trap

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.2. I am trying to use "trap" command to capture abnormal or error in my shell script but I am also trying to manually trigger "Error" exit.

I have tried exit 1, but it won't trigger "Error" signal.

```
#!/bin/bash

func()
{
    exit 1
}

trap "echo hi" INT TERM ERR
func
```

Not sure how to manually trigger "Error" exit signal?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

the `ERR` trap is not to run code when the shell itself exits with a non-zero error code, but when any command run by that shell that is not part of a *condition* (like in `if cmd...`, or `cmd || ...`...) exits with a non-zero exit status (the same conditions as what causes `set -e` to exit the shell).

If you want to run code upon exit of the shell with non-zero exit status, you should add a trap on `EXIT` instead and check `$?` there:

```
trap '[ "$?" -eq 0 ] || echo hi' EXIT
```

Note however that upon a trapped signal, both the signal trap and the EXIT trap would be run, so you may want to do it like:

```
unset killed_by
trap 'killed_by=INT;exit' INT
trap 'killed_by=TERM;exit' TERM
trap '
  ret=$?
  if [ -n "$killed_by" ]; then
    echo >&2 "Ouch! Killed by $killed_by"
    exit 1
  elif [ "$ret" -ne 0 ]; then
    echo >&2 "Died with error code $ret"
  fi' EXIT
```

Or to use exit status like `$((signum + 128))` upon signals:

```
for sig in INT TERM HUP; do
  trap "exit $((128 + $(kill -l "$sig")))" "$sig"
done
trap '
  ret=$?
  [ "$ret" -eq 0 ] || echo >&2 "Bye: $ret"' EXIT
```

Note however that exiting normally upon SIGINT or SIGQUIT has potential annoying side effects when your parent process is a shell like `bash` that implements the [*wait and cooperative exit*](http://www.cons.org/cracauer/sigint.html) handling of terminal interrupt. So, you may want to make sure to kill yourself with the same signal instead so as to report to your parent that you were indeed interrupted, and that it should consider exiting itself as well if it received a SIGINT/SIGQUIT.

```
unset killed_by
for sig in INT QUIT TERM HUP; do
  trap "exit $((128 + $(kill -l "$sig"))); killed_by=$sig" "$sig"
done
trap '
  ret=$?
  [ "$ret" -eq 0 ] || echo >&2 "Bye: $ret"
  if [ -n "$killed_by" ]; then
    trap - "$killed_by" # reset handler
    # ulimit -c 0 # possibly disable core dumps
    kill -s "$killed_by" "$$"
  else
    exec "$ret"
  fi' EXIT
```

If you want the `ERR` trap to fire, just run a command with a non-zero exit status like  `false` or `test`.

Answer (score 8):

Use return, not exit, to set the status on exit from a function (if the function falls-through without a return, the status is that of the last statement executed.) If you substitute `return` for `exit` in the question's example, it will work as I think you intended: the trap will be triggered on the ERR pseudo-signal and 'hi' will be printed. For additional considerations, try this:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

func()
{
    echo 'in func'
    return 99
    echo 'still in func'
}

trap 'echo "done"' EXIT
trap 'status=$?; echo "error status is $status"; trap - EXIT; exit $status' ERR
func
echo 'returned from func'
```

You can try various modifications, such as returning 0, commenting out the ERR trap, not canceling the EXIT trap within the ERR handler, not exiting from the ERR handler, or removing the return and putting `false` as the last statement in func.