# How to have a bash script perform a specific action on errors of _each_ command?

Tags: bash, ksh, exit, error-handling

Similarly to `set -e` performs an `exit` on "uncaught" `$? != 0`, I'd like to have this event trigger the execution of another command, e.g. a `logger` call. How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As hinted at in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79648/how-to-trigger-error-using-trap-command), the answer is setting up a `trap` on the `ERR` signal - basically `set -e` corresponds to `trap 'exit' ERR`. So to e.g. log errors but continue execution, use

```
trap 'logger -t myscriptname "Command $BASH_COMMAND exited with code $?"' ERR
```

In bash, the variable `$BASH_COMMAND` contains the offending command. `$?` contains the exit code of the last command executed - note that if you want to perform multiple actions, e.g. `logger ...; echo $?` the `$?` will contain `logger`'s exit code, not `$BASH_COMMAND`'s one, so you may have to store it in a variable first, e.g.

```
trap 'EXITCODE=$?; logger -t "Command $BASH_COMMAND exited with code $EXITCODE"; echo "$BASH_COMMAND at line $LINENO exited with code $EXITCODE"' ERR
```

Of course you might be better off declaring a function and passing it the `$?` and `$BASH_COMMAND` instead of such a long line!

Comment: @Gilles It's a bit sneaky to edit in a [tag:ksh] into the question to require this edit :P But while you're at it, is there a similar variable in ksh and are there other important differences?